# Using Outlook via win32com, suddenly getting runtime error '_Folders' object is not callable`

Tags: python, automation, outlook, win32com

My code was running quite happily, until today:

```
import win32com.client as wc

ol = wc.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

sess = ol.Session
fldrs = sess.Folders

fldr = fldrs('a.person@somewhere.com')
```

But today, I get the runtime error:
`'_Folders' object is not callable`
when I try to get a named folder.

But, if I change the offending line to:

`fldr = fldrs['a.person@somewhere.com']`

ie, I change from '()' to '[]' subscripting then it runs again happily

I haven't installed any new Python packages (running pywin32 v300, Python 3.7), or modified my Office installation (Office 365 current channel).

The only thing I have been doing between now and yesterday is playing around with `win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents()` for Outlook in a different Python application. Could I have somehow changed a cached dispatch interface?

UPDATE: I experienced some other odd behaviour automating Excel.

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('test.xlsx', False, False, None)
ws = wb.Worksheets[0]
```

Was working fine, but failed when I tried to access any of the dispatch constants: eg win32com.client.constants.xlAfterOrEqualTo. I updated pywin32 from 300 to 301, and changed the object creation line to:

```
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
```

Now, the **`Worksheets[]` call failed, until I changed the index from 0 to 1**. I switched back to the simpler win32com.client.Dispatch() but the index still had to be 1.

On the positive side, the call to `win32com.client.constants` now worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is using the default indexed property. If you prefer `()`, use `fldrs.Item('a.person@somewhere.com')`

Comment: Thanks. I don't prefer either. It is just that I had a script which has worked happily for the past 6 months with `()` but failed today and required me to edit to `[]`. I get regular Office updates so perhaps the type library has changed.

Comment: No, the type library is always backward compatible. That's the whole premise of COM. Is your Python version still the same?

Comment: Yes, been on 3.7 for a while now. I'm going to put it down to 'one of those things' and move on, I guess! Thanks for considering the question.