# Win32com excel find() output is not consistent when run in .py and in .exe

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, win32com

When I run the code below, I get different results when I run in .py compared to when I run in .exe using pyinstaller

```
import win32com.client
import os

ConfigMacroName = "test.xls"
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
Configmacrowb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.getcwd()+ "\\Completed\\" + ConfigMacroName)
SlotPlansheet = Configmacrowb.Sheets("SlotPlan")
Header = SlotPlansheet.Rows(1)
SOcol = Header.Find('SO', LookAt=1).Column #I used LookAt=1 which is equivalent to LookAt:=xlWhole in excel VBA
SOlinecol = Header.Find('SO Line').Column
print("SO is " + str(SOcol) + "\nSo line is " + str(SOlinecol))

SlotPlansheet = None
Configmacrowb.Close(False)
Configmacrowb = None
xl.Quit()
xl = None
```

The excel input

[image]

The output in .py

[image]

The output in .exe

[image]

The output in .py file is the correct output I need. If I run it in .exe there will be duplicate variable since they both will refer to column B. For temporary solution I can just loop through the header to check each cell.

But I'm using find() function a lot so I don't know if my other programs are also affected by this inconsistency

Comment: Can you show us the input spreadsheet data? And what happens if you use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(‘Excel.Application’)`?

Comment: @DS_London surprisingly that fixed it. I haven't implement it on my actual work, but the test file shows if i use `EnsureDispatch`, both .py and .exe will call out the correct column. I read a bit about the differences, so now I'm wondering if there's any downside of using `EnsureDispatch`

Comment: @DS_London anyway you can answer this post with that suggestion and I'll choose it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the object creation line to:

`xl=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')`

In my experience, the `win32com.client.Dispatch()` function can sometimes cause issues in that it does not guarantee the same result every time it runs. The caller doesn't know if they have an early- or late-bound object. If you have no cached makepy files then you will get a late-bound IDispatch automation interface, but if win32com finds an early-bound interface then it will use it (even if it wasn't your programme that created it). Hence code that ran fine previously may stop working.

Unless you have a good reason to be indifferent, I think it is better to be explicit and choose `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` or `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch()` for early- or late-binding respectively. I generally choose the EnsureDispatch() route, as it is quicker, enforces case-sensitivity, and gives access to any constants in the type library (eg `win32com.client.constants.xlWhole`) rather than rely on 'magic' integers.

Also, in the past, I have experienced odd behaviour around indexing (eg this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101334/using-outlook-via-win32com-suddenly-getting-runtime-error-folders-object-is)), and this was cured by deleted any gencache wrappers (see below).

Add this line to your debug code:

`print('Cache directory:',win32com.client.gencache.GetGeneratePath())`

This will tell you where the `gencache` early-binding python files are being generated, and where `win32com.client.Dispatch()` will look for any cached wrapper files to attempt early-binding. If you want to clear the cached of generated files just delete the contents of this directory. It will be interesting to see if the OP's two routes have the same directory.