# pyinstaller package not behaving the same as the script execution

Tags: python, excel, automation, pyinstaller, pywin32

I'm having this issue with pyinstaller,

so i have the following code :

```
import win32com.client as win32


def create_report(report):

    # launching xl app
    xlApp = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    # selecting data sheet
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(report)
    work_sheets = [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets]
    ws = wb.Worksheets(work_sheets[0])

    # adding pt sheet
    ws_pt_name = 'Synthese'
    wb.Sheets.Add().Name = ws_pt_name
    ws_pt = wb.Worksheets(ws_pt_name)

    # create pivot table cache connection
    pt_cache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(1, ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

    # create pivot table designer/editor
    pt = pt_cache.CreatePivotTable(ws_pt.Range("A3"), "Summary")

    # row and column grandtotals
    pt.ColumnGrand = True
    pt.RowGrand = True

    # change report layout
    pt.RowAxisLayout(0)

    # change pivot table style
    pt.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight16"

    def creat_pt(pt):
        # add row
        field_rows = {}
        field_rows["Date"] = pt.PivotFields("Date")

        # add value
        field_values = {}
        field_values["Name"] = pt.PivotFields("Name")

        # add cols
        field_cols = {}
        field_cols["State"] = pt.PivotFields("State")

        # insert row fields to pivot table design
        field_rows["Date"].Orientation = 1  # 1 for row orientation

        # insert data/value to pivot table design
        field_values["Name"].Orientation = 4  # 4 for data/value
        field_values["Name"].Function = -4112  # -4112 for xlCount
        field_values["Name"].NumberFormat = "#,##0"  # "#,##0" for number format

        # insert col field to pivot table design
        field_cols["State"].Orientation = 2  # 2 for col orientation

        # grouping date field by year and month
        wb.Sheets(ws_pt_name).Range("A5").Group(Periods=(False, False, False, False, True, False, True))

        wb.Save()

    creat_pt(pt)
```

i'm creating an excel pivot table and i get this result (the result i'm looking for) when i execute the code from pycharm in my venv :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGN1m.png)

when i pack the script with pyinstaller, i get the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g26rw.png)

i would like the date field to be grouped by year and month (like the pic below)
it seems that with the pyinstaller packed executable, the following line doesn't take effect :

```
wb.Sheets(ws_pt_name).Range("A5").Group(Periods=(False, False, False, False, True, False, True))
```

i tried to add all the relevant libraries in my venv to the pyinstaller commands (win32, win32c, openpyxl, xlwriter, xlwt, xlrd ...), i get the same result

what do you guys think ?

Comment: i solved this by putting `xlApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")` instead of `xlApp = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")` , now the executable package generated by pyinstaller is consistant and executes Group(), the solution is inspired from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108359/win32com-excel-find-output-is-not-consistent-when-run-in-py-and-in-exe)